# Updating repository after Checkout with Empty depth

Tags: c#, svn, sharpsvn, sparse-checkout

I`m using SharpSVN.
How can I split Checkout method logic into two steps:

1. Create an empty svn folder
2. Update to HEAD revision

Here is how do I do the first step with `SvnDepth.Empty` argument

```
var args = new SvnCheckOutArgs() {Depth = SvnDepth.Empty};
result = svnClient.CheckOut(new SvnUriTarget(syncConnectionData.Url), syncConnectionData.RootPath, args);
```

But then if I try to Update like this:

```
var updateArgs = new SvnUpdateArgs() { Depth = SvnDepth.Infinity};
svnClient.Update(syncConnectionData.RootPath, updateArgs);
```

I get no updates. The repository on svn server is not empty.

So the question is: how do I correctly update to the latest revision after making Checkout with Empty depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, found the solution =) Needed to use `KeepDepth` property of `SvnUpdateArgs`

Here is the working code for Update after Sparse-Checkout

```
    var updateArgs = new SvnUpdateArgs() { Depth = SvnDepth.Infinity, KeepDepth = true };
    svnClient.Update(syncConnectionData.RootPath, updateArgs);
```

Comment: Nice catch! Please remember to mark this as the answer after the obligatory waiting period. :)